# Partial Differentiation on the Wave Equation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, wave-equation

Consider the equation $$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=c^2\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$ where c is some constant. Define new variables, $\sigma=x-ct $ and $\gamma=x+ct$. Now show that the equation becomes $$\frac{d^2u}{d\gamma d\sigma}$$

Can somebody explain what is happening here. I do not know what $u$ is nor what it is a function of. Would this have anything to deal with the wave equation in Physics?

This question is the same as to [$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}-c^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=0\text{ implies } \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z \partial y}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023817/frac-partial2-u-partial-t2-c2-frac-partial2u-partial-x2-0-text-i?rq=1)

Comment: @A.F.23: Explain this to him with your notation! :)